# Angular + webauthn = Property 'credentials' does not exist on type 'Navigator'?

Tags: angular, definitelytyped, webauthn

I've been trying to add webauthn to an Angular app. This MDN page outlines the necessary steps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API

The important thing is that using the APIs requires access to `navigator.credentials`. However, Angular does not compile when I try to reference that. For example, this line of code:

```
await navigator.credentials.create({...});
```

...produces this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'credentials' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

Now I know I can do something like this:

```
declare global {
  interface Navigator {
    credentials: {
      create(): void,
      get(): void
    }
  }
}
```

But it's really tedious to have to write all that TypeScript for the entire [`CredentialsContainer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CredentialsContainer) API. Besides, someone already did all that work in `DefinitelyTyped`, right?

So I added [`@types/webappsec-credential-management`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webappsec-credential-management) to my project with `npm install --save-dev @types/webappsec-credential-management`.

Now Visual Studio Code knows what to do; I've got autocomplete and everything.

But Angular still won't compile. It gives the same error above.

What do I need to do to get Angular to recognize `navigator.credentials`?

Answer (score 10):

You can proceed as follow:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/webappsec-credential-management
```

then edit angular's `<project>/src/tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": [
      "@types/webappsec-credential-management"
    ]
    ...
}
```

It is necessary to edit angular's own `tsconfig.app.json` as it will be used to compile angular's code. The root `tsconfig.json` is used for bootstrapping and general (vscode) typescript config. So if you just add  `@types/webappsec-credential-management` to your types it will be recognised in your editor but it will be ignored by angular's very own compiler and thus creating this typing error:

`error TS2339: Property 'credentials' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.`.

Answer (score 2):

I was missing this at the top of my .ts file:

```js
/// <reference types="@types/webappsec-credential-management" />
```

I also needed to `ng update typescript` and `ng update @angular/cli`.